# Как разрешить использование некоторых html-тегов

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

Я хочу **разрешить** использование тегов: `<b>, <i>, <kbd> и т.д.`.

По-этому в коде я использую функцию `strip_tags()`, но она удаляет **html, php теги**. В свою очередь, `htmlspecialchars()` просто заменяет на соответствующие символы, а значит, что если я потом буду где-то использовать их (`htmlspecialchars_decode`), то будут выводится все теги **НЕ экранированы**, что грозит безопасности.

---

**Как разрешить отображать только некоторые теги, или может все же использовать `strip_tags`, но с шансом неудобства для пользователя** *(хоть пользователь, который хочет их использовать далеко уже не пользователь:))* ?

Comment: allowable_tags нужно указать

Comment: Про strip_tags(): `Внимание Эта функция не изменяет атрибуты тегов, разрешенных с помощью allowable_tags, включая такие атрибуты как style и onmouseover, которые могут быть использованы озорными пользователями при посылке текста, отображаемого также и другим пользователям.`

Comment: Можно глянуть в эту сторону --> http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @Visman, я не уточнил, что мне не нужно удалять сам тег, пусть он будет. `strip_tags()` ведь удаляет теги, а мне не нужно их удалять. Нужно оставить выбранные.

Comment: С давних времён в php для этого используют jevix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - сделать white list на определенные теги, а те, которые не находятся в этом списке, удалять.

Допустим нам разрешены теги `<b>` и `<i>`. Мы заводим какую-нибудь коллекцию, в которую помещаем эти 2 тега. Далее создаем регулярное выражение, которое идентифицирует тег. После этого мы последовательно в подаваемой на вход строке ищем любые теги по этому регулярному выражению и, если тег не содержится в нашей коллекции, заменяем его на пустую строку.

Comment: Можете рассказать более детальный алгоритм?

Comment: Перенесите комментарий в ответ.

Comment: Тут нужно быть очень осторожным с реализацией данной идеи. Например, можно написать такую глупую регулярку, которая из текста `<sc<foo>cipt>` вырежет запрещённый тег `<foo>` и в результате получится `<script>`. Нужно будет или регулярку умнее делать, или несколько итераций прогонять, или ещё что-то менять. Хотя в любом случае наверно лучше просто взять jevix)

Comment: А ещё в зависимости от регулярки HTML-атрибуты могут не пропускаться или пропускаться. Если они пропускаются, то это путь к XSS.

Comment: А ещё всё равно нужно предусмотреть защиту, чтобы простой текст `<!--` не сломал весь сайт нахрен. @Cricket, если вы задумываетесь о безопасности, учитывайте это :)

Comment: Согласен, реализуя этот вариант, нужно быть крайне осторожным.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы уже после работы `htmlspecialchars()` реплейсил некоторые допустимые теги, т.е `&lt;(.*)&gt;` -> `<b>$1</b>`.

Можно регуляркой, или встроенным парсером - http://php.net/manual/ru/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов реализации большое количество. Посмотри в сторону [BBCode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)

Т.е. пользователь пишет текст, и хочет, что бы жирный был [b]**жирным**[\b].

Ты спокойно можешь сохранять BBCode в SqlDataBase и т.д.

Но перед выводом сообщения ты просто меняешь [b] на < b>, [\b] на <\b>.

А вот что то там пытаться разрешать, я очень не советую. Что запрещено или опасно, пусть и будет таковым.